# ec2 reserved instance data transfer cost

Tags: amazon-ec2, reserved-instances

What is the cost for data transfer out for AWS EC2 reserved instances?
This is clear for EC2 On-Demand instances and it is stated on the pricing page, but I can't find any information about data transfer-out costs for reserved instances. Anyone with the experience of reserved instances please share your knowledge.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. AWS has a tool: monthly calculator. Data Transfer out cost is same as on-demand instances.